# Push Notification not coming on device from server through APNS to device

Tags: iphone

What are the reasons,that push notification is not coming on my device 
when my app is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: to handle an incoming push notification that causes the launch of the application, this method (application:didReceiveRemoteNotification) is not invoked for that push notification.

Cf [Apple Online Doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)

Comment: then what should i do?bcoz whnever sometimes popup comes at that time there are 2 options 1>close 2>view and when i click on view at that time didFinishLaunchingWithOptions this method calls and it process my statemaintainance code which is working perfectly but there is no reliability of notification or u can say alert